# meaning of 'account for '

Tags: meaning

> ''Bonn meeting would also include proposals for how action taken could be monitored, *accounted for* and kept transparent while providing some level of flexibility '

What is the meaning of *'accounted for'*  in the previously given sentence?

I have already checked the meaning for the same on various online dictionaries, even I know its meaning but, here in this particular sentence I am unable to find out the context on which it has been used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accounting is the process of keeping records of something.

Here "accounted for" means keeping a record of all actions taken and their details - by whom, when, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this sense, I would say that "*actions accounted for*" refers to actions for which a record has been kept; colloquially, kept track of.